# Is there any mentions in scriptures about the usage of gemstones in astrology and their relationships with the navgrahas?

Tags: scripture, astrology

In vedic astrology the usage of precious gemstones is common practice to resolve issues in a person's life related to the navgrahas. However,which scriptures mention the relationships of those gemstones to the navgrahas. Also, where can we find justifications for the usage of gemstones as remedies for astrological related issues and what are the criteria(e.g weight,color,clarity of gemstones) in determining the gemstones to be used.
If possible,can we get all/most of the vedic texts that make such mentions for better comparison and analysis.

Comment: Something related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18646/is-there-any-mention-of-gem-stones-in-puranas/18655#18655

Comment: @Rickross Yes the post give details about the gemstones to some extent but I need more details for e.g about the relationships with the navgrahas. Also,from the post I found this:
"sapphires were grouped onto four ‘varnas’ or classes. Hindus were only allowed to wear sapphires with the color designated for their caste. The Brahmins’ stone was whitish blue, the Kshatriyas’ was a reddish blue, the Vaishyas’ was yellowish blue, and the Sudras’ was a dark or blackish blue." - Does this applies to other gemstones?

Comment: @Rickross are there any Texts that deal with this in a more logical approach?

Comment: Yes co-relations (like Ruby with Sun, Coral with Mars etc) exist in Jyotisha texts