# Do ancient astrology books say to wear gemstones to increase the effects of planets?

Tags: scripture, astrology, navagraha

Do ancient scriptures like Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra or Brighu Samhita or Brihajjatakam etc. say anything on wearing gemstones to **increase the effect** of a Planet?

Like we have:

- Ruby for Sun
- Pearl for Moon
- Red Coral for Mars
- Emerald for Mercury
- Yellow Sapphire for Jupiter
- Diamond for Venus
- Blue Sapphire for Saturn
- Hessonite for Rahu
- Cat's Eye for Ketu

Apart from these, there are various stones which can be used as substitutes according to Astrology. So does any scripture mentions about them as a remedy to increase the effect of planets?

---

**NOTE: I want answer from the perspective of Astrology**

Comment: This might be slightly helpful https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18646/is-there-any-mention-of-gem-stones-in-puranas/21979#21979

Comment: @devibhakt Yes it was helpful but I wanted the answer from a different perspective. Thanks for helping. I have edited the question now for better understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

Refer the following **Grantas** (written in Sanskrit) to know about planetary gemstones:

- `Jataka Parijata by Vaidyanatha Dixita (Chapter-II Sloka-21).`
- `Phala Deepika by Mantreswara (Chapter-II Sloka-29).`

Comment: Thank a lot for answering! Could you elaborate more like what ancient books say on effects after wearing the gemstones and substitutes of the gemstones. The slokas provided only give info regarding which stone corresponds to which graha.

Comment: @LSSJ Broly, here is my reply for your comment.
No Granta (Astrology) advocates substitutes! Go only for original gemstones (Navaratna/नवरत्न)!! 
Please refer my answers on Quora Platform related to stones as given below:

Comment: 1) https://www.quora.com/Can-talismans-and-amulets-be-used-to-focus-magical-intent/answer/Krishna-Joshiar

2) https://www.quora.com/Which-Hindu-magical-stones-are-believed-to-defeat-gods/answer/Krishna-Joshiar

3) https://www.quora.com/Im-using-2-1-CT-yellow-sapphire-light-in-colour-since-16-years-for-my-right-index-finger-yesterday-I-purchased-3-12-CT-yellow-sapphire-dark-in-colour-shall-I-use-it-for-my-left-index-finger/answer/Krishna-Joshiar

Comment: Thanks sir. But Jataka Parijata is only saying which gemstone corresponds to which graha. I'm asking that which ancient books say to wear the gemstones for the planets. How much ratti, which finger, etc. are present in which book and how it is calculated? Is it a modern practice?